# How to query multiple models in views and pass them to one template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a path lab database system, Where I have models as follows:

1. Client model: to store client name
2. CBC test model: child to client model.
3. Liver test model: child to client model.
4. kidney function test model: child to client model.

my purpose is that if we enter client id and date to form it goes to result page and shows all the test performed to that particular client on that date.
I made a client model and models for each tests.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import client, cbc, lft, kft
from django.db.models import Q

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'vmr/index.html')

def result(request):
    client = request.POST['client']
    date = request.POST['date']
    r = cbc.objects.filter(Q(id = client ) & Q(Date__iexact = date))
    l = lft.objects.filter(Q(id = client ) & Q(Date__iexact = date))
    k = kft.objects.filter(Q(id = client ) & Q(Date__iexact = date))
    context = { "results": r, "liver": l, "kidney":k}
    return render(request, 'vmr/result.html', context=context )
```

My Result template for results is:

```
         {% if results %}

        {% for result in results%}

    <h3 style="padding-left: 10%;"> DATE:{{result.Date}} </h3>
    
        <table style="width:70%">
        <tr>
            <th>PARAMETER</th>
            <th>UNIT</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
            <th>RANGE</th>
            <th>INFERENCE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> RBC </td>
            <td> million/mm3 </td>
            <td> {{result.RBC}} </td>
            <td> 5.5-8.5 </td>
            <td> {% if result.RBC < 12 %}
             ANEMIA
            {% else %}
            NORMAL
            {% endif %} </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> HEMOGLOBIN </td>
            <td> g/dl </td>
            <td> {{result.Hemoglobin}} </td>
            <td> 12-18 </td>
            <td> {% if result.Hemoglobin < 12 %}
             ANEMIA
            {% else %}
            NORMAL
            {% endif %} </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}
      
        <h3>LIVER TEST</h3>
          {% if livers %}

          {% for liver in livers%}

    <h3 style="padding-left: 10%;"> DATE:{{liver.Date}} </h3>
    
        <table style="width:70%">
        <tr>
            <th>PARAMETER</th>
            <th>UNIT</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
            <th>RANGE</th>
            <th>INFERENCE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> SGOT </td>
            <td> million/mm3 </td>
            <td> {{liver.SGOT}} </td>
            <td> 9-49 </td>
            <td> {% if liver.SGOT < 9 %}
             ABNORMAL VALUE
            {% elif liver.SGOT > 49 %}
             HEPATOMEGALY
            {% else %}
            NORMAL
            {% endif %}
         </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </table>
```

my form index template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{% url 'result'%}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="client">
    <label for="client">CLIENT ID</label>
    <input type="date" name = "date">
    <label for="date">DATE</label>
    <button type="submit" name = "submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is fine for cbc results but when I include tags for liver and kidney it shows error.

What is the correct approach to get all tests for a client on particular date on one template?

One approach I think can  be if I create a Tests Records Model which is child of client, cbc, lft, kft so that we query Records model by date and client id and get everything on page.

Please can anyone suggest best method to get all test done to a particular client on particular date on one page.

Comment: What is the error you get? I don't see you using liver or kidney QuerySets in your template. Please edit the question and add that information with the full error stacktrace if possible.

Comment: The EDIT you made does not show the problems or errors you are having. Did you get it to work? Did my answer help you to find a solution?

Comment: There was problem with html tagging, when corrected the above code worked fine. I didn't need to make any changes to views. Your answer helped to view this code with different aspect. Both your and my approaches are working fine. Thanks for help Ralf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful: `request.POST` contains strings, so `date` will NOT yet be a `datetime.date` object.
You might want to add explicit date parsing, maybe something like this:

```
try:
    date = datetime.datetime\
        .strptime(request.POST.get('date', ''), '%d-%m-%Y')\
        .date()
except ValueError:
    date = None
```

And maybe you want to transform `request.POST['client']` from string to integer as well (I assume that ID is integer, because that is the standard Django ID field). Or maybe you even want to query the `client` model to ensure that the given client ID exists:

```
try:
    client_obj = client.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('client', ''))
    client_id = client_obj.pk
except (ValueError, client.DoesNotExist):
    client_id = None
```

And your queries can be simplified, because the `Q()` is not necessary for simple queries; also the `__exact` filter is not necessary in this part, because it is the default filter.

And last: you don't show your models, but I assume that the results, liver and kidney models each have a `ForeingKey` to `client`, so you should filter by `client_id`, not on `id` directly.

---

So your final view could look something like this:

```
def result(request):
    try:
        client_obj = client.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('client', ''))
        client_id = client_obj.pk
    except (ValueError, client.DoesNotExist):
        client_id = None

    try:
        date = datetime.datetime\
            .strptime(request.POST.get('date', ''), '%d-%m-%Y')\
            .date()
    except ValueError:
        date = None

    context = {
        "results": cbc.objects.filter(client_id=client_id, Date=date),
        "liver":   lft.objects.filter(client_id=client_id, Date=date),
        "kidney":  kft.objects.filter(client_id=client_id, Date=date),
    }

    return render(request, 'vmr/result.html', context=context)
```